# How to prove $f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))$ and $g(n) ∈ O(h(n)) \implies f(n) ∈ Θ(h(n))$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, data-structure

I'm stuck at proving this formally.
As far as I got is that I know that

$f(n) ∈ \Theta(g(n))$ means $c_1 g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_2 g(n)$

$g(n) ∈ O(h(n))$ means $g(n) \leq c_3 h(n)$

$f(n) ∈ Θ(h(n))$ means $c_4 h(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_5 h(n)$

If I just look at it I can tell that it's false, but I cant prove it formally.
My mind says if $f(n)$ grows the same as $g(n)$ and $g(n)$ grows less than $h(n)$, $f(n)$ obviously cant grow the same as $h(n)$, because $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ grow equally.

Somehow I cant express that formally.

I'm thankful for any help

Comment: This statement is false. To prove that find a counterexample. Did you try some counterexamples so far ? Also your definitions of $\Theta()$ and $O()$ are not fully correct. There exists an $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$...
Also please use math mode / latex - see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), I have edited your question to include it.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your notation or question. Isn’t $h(n)=n^2, g(n)=f(n)=n$ a counter example?

Comment: Are you supposed to prove this statement?

Comment: Yes I am supposed to prove this statement. I have thought about the same thing you said as well but somehow I dont think f(n) = g(n) is correct.